# asks the user for particular currency note preference The user can be given a maximum of 200 notes of his preferred choice

Tags: javascript, html, css, logic

Write a JavaScript program which accepts amount in rupees as input (integer) within Range from
Rs. 100 to Rs. 100000 and display the total number of currency notes of Rs. 500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, and 1.

```
// function to count and print currency notes
const countCurrency = () => {
  // get value of input field (Amount)
  let inputAmount = document.getElementById('inputAmount').value;
  // get value of input field (userChoice)
  let userChoice=document.getElementById('userChoice').value
  //check inputAmount is greater than 100 & less than 100000 
  if (inputAmount >= 100 && inputAmount <= 100000) {
    let notes = [500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1]
    let noteCounter = Array(7).fill(0)

    // note counting
    for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
      noteCounter[i] = Math.floor(inputAmount / notes[i])
      inputAmount = inputAmount - noteCounter[i] * notes[i]
      console.log(noteCounter[i] )
    }
    
    // Print notes
    for (let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
      if (noteCounter[i] != 0) {
        //use DOM to show final result
        let mainContainer=document.getElementById('mainContainer');
        let createDiv = document.createElement("li");
        createDiv.style.marginTop = "10px";
        createDiv.style.marginLeft = "10px";
        createDiv.style.fontSize = "20px";
        createDiv.style.paddingRight = "10px";
        createDiv.innerHTML =`${noteCounter[i]} Note(s) of ${notes[i]}`;
        mainContainer.appendChild(createDiv);
      } 
    }
    // empty input field after result
    document.getElementById('inputAmount').value=''
  } else {
    document.getElementById('headContent').innerHTML='Invalid Amount!'
  }
}
```

but i need to add some more logic's i.e  asks the user for particular currency note preference  The user can be given a maximum of 200 notes of his preferred choice.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btnFunc = () => {
    let inputAmount = parseInt(document.getElementById("amountEntered").value);
    let userPref = parseInt(document.getElementById("userPref").value);
    //let currencyLimit = 200;
    let notes = [500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 1];
    let noteCounter=[];
    let prefCurr = Math.floor(inputAmount / userPref);
    console.log(noteCounter, userPref, prefCurr);
    for(let i = 0; i < notes.length; i++)
    {
        if(userPref === notes[i])
        {
            notes.splice(i,1)
        }
       
    }
    if(prefCurr > 200)
    {
        let prefCurrencyAmount = userPref * 200
        let balanceAmount = inputAmount - prefCurrencyAmount
        console.log(balanceAmount, notes);
        let prefValue = document.getElementById('prefValue')
        prefValue.innerHTML = userPref + ': ' + 200 + '=' +  userPref * 200
        for(j = 0; j < notes.length; j++)
        {
            if(balanceAmount >= notes[j]){
            noteCounter = Math.floor(balanceAmount/notes[j])
            balanceAmount -= noteCounter*notes[j]
            console.log(notes[j] + ": " + noteCounter + '= ' + notes[j]*noteCounter)  }
            let remainValue = document.getElementById('remainValue')
            let p = document.createElement('p')
            p.innerText = notes[j] + ": " + noteCounter + '= ' + notes[j]*noteCounter
            remainValue.appendChild(p)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        let prefCurrencyAmount = userPref * prefCurr
        let balanceAmount = inputAmount - prefCurrencyAmount
        console.log(balanceAmount, notes);
        let prefValue = document.getElementById('prefValue')
        prefValue.innerHTML = userPref + ': ' + prefCurr + '=' +  userPref * prefCurr
        console.log(userPref + ': ' + prefCurr + '=' +   userPref * prefCurr)
        for(k = 0; k < notes.length; k++)
        {
            if(balanceAmount >= notes[k]){
            noteCounter = Math.floor(balanceAmount/notes[k])
            balanceAmount -= noteCounter*notes[k]
            console.log(notes[k] + ": " + noteCounter + '= ' + notes[k]*noteCounter)  }
            let remainValue = document.getElementById('remainValue')
            let p = document.createElement('p')
            p.innerText = notes[k] + ": " + noteCounter + '= ' + notes[k]*noteCounter
            remainValue.appendChild(p)
        }
    }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


    <input type="text" name="amountEntered" id="amountEntered" />
    <select id="userPref">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Your Currency Note Prefrenece</option>
        <option value="500">500</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
    </select>
    <button onclick="btnFunc()">Submit</button> 
    <div id="prefValue"></div>
    <div id="remainValue"></div>
    

    <script src="./app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

May be this will help you.